# Internal self-test error MLParseStream|c|297

Tags: graphics3d, warning-messages

I have been plotting time-dependent vectors.
Earlier I used the following plotting options:

```
CLB4D[t_] := {CLBx[t], CLBy[t], CLBz[t], t};

tempdata = Table[CLB4D[t], {t, 0, d, (0.01/\[Omega])}];
tempdata[[All, 4]] = Rescale[tempdata[[All, 4]], {0, d}];
clrfnct[x_, cf_] := ColorData[cf][1 - x[[4]]];
Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.013], 
Point[#[[1 ;; 3]], VertexColors -> clrfnct[#, "SolarColors"]] & /@ 
tempdata, Opacity[0.01], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}]}, Boxed -> False, 
Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

where CLB4D[t] is the vector, specifying a point in 3D-space, with a color that corresponds to a time-coordinate. The components of this vector are defined in the same module, which then plots the answer. Actually, I have several different modules with different definitions for vectors that I am comparing.

It worked well, but I wished to tweak the options to get a clearer plot (changing the visual appearance wasn't just my wish, either). I am happy with the following options:

```
CLB4D[t_] := {CLBx[t], CLBy[t], CLBz[t], t};

tempdata = Table[CLB4D[t], {t, 0, 2*pi/f, (2*pi/f)/150}];
tempdata[[All, 4]] = Rescale[tempdata[[All, 4]], {0, 2*pi/f}];
clrfnct[x_, cf_] := ColorData[cf][1 - x[[4]]];
Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.010], 
Point[#[[1 ;; 3]], VertexColors -> clrfnct[#, "SolarColors"]] & /@ 
tempdata, Opacity[0.5], pic[[1]], pic2[[1]]}, Boxed -> False, 
Axes -> False, 
PlotLabel -> 
Style["text and "<>ToString[variables_from_the_module], FontSize -> 16, FontFamily -> "STIX"], 
 ViewPoint -> {1.14, -3.09, 0.77}]
```

There, pic and pic2 are parametricplot3d's of unit circles, and the coordinate axes from 0 to 1. These are always plotted as a reference. 
The trouble is that whenever I have any plot that takes, say, 20 minutes or an hour from the local computer to calculate (or would take in the previous style), after evaluating it for a long while, Mathematica just freezes, and most of the time I have to kill it, or it crashes. Finally, it gave me the **Self-test error MLParseStream|c|297** instead of crashing. It fails to evaluate with both Linux and Mac. I got this message on a Mac. 
If the plot only takes for a couple of seconds to evaluate, it manages to do this. Sometimes it has managed to evaluate a heavier plot, but will crash when I try to save .nb or export the plot as a PDF.

I have no idea what goes wrong, nor have I found out what the message is about. I have not changed any other definitions in the module. I also noticed that taking away the option "viewpoint" does not remove the problem.

Any suggestions?

I am using version 9 of Mathematica.

Comment: "I can provide more code about the definitions of the vectors, if it is needed" - Please do, so others can replicate your scenario!

Comment: Here you go, I hope that helps.

Comment: one problem in replicating the scenario is that it might take a while (meaning tens of minutes) for it to stop evaluating, but it doesn't produce the error for very short evaluations at all.

Comment: I actually got this to run on the mac just by optimizing the code a bit. Still: in general, Mathematica hasn't had the habit of lagging and crashing away like that in cases where evaluation has taken longer than with these. And it really seemed to jam the Ubuntu system.

Comment: Do post your optimized code as an answer! Self-answering is allowed :-)